# How to export data from mongoDB to MYSQL using pentaho?

Tags: mongodb, mysql, pentaho, kettle

I am trying to export and import data from mongoDB to MYSQL DB using Kettle(Pentaho). I am using MongoDB input and table output steps, but this is not working, I guess I am missing something. Can anyone provide an example to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give more details about your problem: what happens exactly? message errors.. etc

Comment: @jipipayo I just used MongoDB input step and gave host name, collections, fields, etc and used table output step to store fields to MySQL table. when I run the transformation, it stopped at MongoDB input step, it won't move any further or producing any error. It just stopped there.

Comment: your approach is good, maybe the mongodb server is not reachable... firewall, dns...   make sure this server is accesible from the same machine you are building the kettle trans.

Comment: what happens when you click on the preview button ,into the MongoDB input step?

Comment: If it stopped but did not produce any error (does it say E=0 for the mongo step?) then it didnt find any data. Check your query/collection name etc.  Also try increasing the log level.

Comment: @jipipayo you are right. The MongoDB input step can't reach the MongoDB server. now fixed it and now I can export the data. Thanks a lot.